# generate range for which std::isalpha evaluates to true

Tags: c++, c++11, locale

This may be a trivial question for some, but I cannot find an appropriate answer. What I'd like is to generate a range (let's say a `std::string`) that contains all possible `char`s for which `std::isalpha` evaluates to `true`.

For example, for the default locale, the string should be `"A...Za...z"`. However, if the locale is french, for example, then accented letters should also belong to the string.

PS: I got a solution from Dieter Lücking, https://stackoverflow.com/a/25125871/3093378
It seems to work on all platforms except mine (`OS X 10.9.4` `g++4.9`, `clang++` LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) ), where it just segfaults when trying to access `table[i]` in the line

```
if(table[i] & ctype::alpha)
```

I wonder if anyone else can reproduce the error on a Mac or any other platform.

Comment: Thought about incrementing and checking a `char` variable with `std::isalpha()` in a loop?

Comment: Yes, something along these lines. I'm playing a bit with frequency analysis on texts, and having such a range would be handy.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/ has an unofficial list for the c-version of `isalpha`.  `isalpha (charT c, const locale& loc)` is locale dependant obviously

Comment: @MooingDuck, thanks for the link, I'm aware of these functions, I just wonder how I would generate the range? Of course a solution is to blindly iterate and test `isalpha` (or use a `std::transform` on a predefined range with `isalpha` as a predicate), but I thought a cleverer solution may exist.

Comment: @vsoftco: You could hardcode the range.  Or test them one at a time.  The only other potential solution I can think of is if there exists some other API that reveals this information, but I doubt it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of classifying characters by generating a set of characters, being alphabetical, you might utilize the ctype-table directly:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

int main() {
    typedef std::ctype<char> ctype;
    std::locale locale;
    const ctype& facet = std::use_facet<ctype>(locale);
    const ctype::mask* table = facet.table();

    // You might skip this and work with the table, only.
    std::string result;
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < facet.table_size; ++i) {
        if(table[i] & ctype::alpha)
            result += char(i);
    }
    std::cout << result << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @vsoftco Running it with valgrind: There is no issue.

Comment: it may have to do with my library implementation then (OS X, g++4.9, clang++)

Comment: The line that messes things up is the `table[i]` access in `if`, will try to figure out what's wrong on my side.

Comment: Would accept your answer as it looks it runs on any platform except OS X, trying to see what is wrong with the implementation, as both `libstdc++` and `libc++` appear to be broken.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a portable solution then I can't think of any reason running `isalpha()` on all possible `char` values wouldn't be your best option.

If platform specific methods are acceptable then you may be able to extract the information from the locale definitions for your platform. Here's some documentation that would help you get started on POSIX platforms: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/basedefs/xbd_chap07.html