# std::locale segfault on OS X, cannot reproduce on any other platform

Tags: c++, c++11, segmentation-fault, locale

I have the following code suggested for a previous question of mine [generate range for which std::isalpha evaluates to true](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25125523/3093378) . It displays all `char`s in the current locale for which `isalpha` evaluates to `true`, so for an english locale it displays `AB...Zab...z`. However, I am getting a `Segmentation fault: 11` on the line `if(table[i] & ctype::alpha)` when trying to access `table`. I compiled it with both g++4.9 and clang++ (Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) ), on OS X Mavericks 10.9.4. On all other platforms (Linux/Solaris) it works, no segmentation faults.

Can anyone point out if there is something broken in the C++'s libc++/libstdc++ on OS X, or at least if the problem is reproducible?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

int main() {
    typedef std::ctype<char> ctype;
    std::locale locale;
    const ctype& facet = std::use_facet<ctype>(locale);
    const ctype::mask* table = facet.table();

    // You might skip this and work with the table, only.
    std::string result;
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < facet.table_size; ++i) {
        if(table[i] & ctype::alpha)
            result += char(i);
    }
    std::cout << result << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

PS: after many hours I found out (following Howard's suggestion) that clang++ was picking up by default libstdc++ (why I have yet to find out), which seem to be broken in terms of locale support. When compiling with libc++, the program works as it is supposed to.

Comment: `facet.table();` in this case will return `classic_table()` as you are using the default C locale, which is a null pointer for OSX. Sadly C++ locale support is very sparse on OSX.

Comment: The lesson here is: Always check that function return values are valid.

Comment: @user657267, thanks! I wonder myself why the heck I haven't check for `nullptr`... Is there any particular reason why locale is not properly supported on OS X?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg lesson not learned well enough :)

Comment: Hopefully is learned now? ;)

Comment: @vsoftco GCC on OSX can only be compiled with the `generic` locale model because the `gnu` model is not supported. I'm guessing the same applies to Clang. The `generic` model only has barebones support for locales (pretty much all you get is the default C locale). Regarding checking the pointer, it's an honest mistake, the return value should be an array of length `table_size` according to the standard and there doesn't seem to be any exception allowed for implementations to provide their own behaviour.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Might as well turn my comments into an answer:

As libstdc++ does not support anything but the 'generic' locale model on OSX, C++ locales are hardly supported at all. Your segfault is caused by `facet.table();` returning a null pointer (this is not actually allowed by the standard).

Sadly the only solution for now is to stay away from locales on OSX altogether, or switch to libc++ instead which as @HowardHinnant points out works fine.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using clang++ (Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) ), on OS X Mavericks 10.9.4, and your program works fine for me.  I added:

```
assert(table != nullptr);
assert(table == facet.classic_table());
```

and both asserts pass.  Compiled with:

```
clang++ test.cpp
```

Comment: It is strange, I'm also using the exact same `clang++`, same OS X version, and tested on both my laptop and iMac at work, and the assert fails (`nullptr`) on both.

Comment: Is your clang++ the same one that came with XCode (as mine is)?

Comment: Yes.  And on this OS/tools the default is to use libc++, as opposed to libstdc++.  And I implemented this part of libc++.  The only explanation I have is that somehow you are picking up the gcc libstdc++.

Comment: Yes! You are right, clang++ is picking up `libstdc++`, I compiled it now with `-stdlib=libc++` and it works as it is supposed to. Another g++ issue... And why is clang++ using libstdc++ I yet have to find out, it is probably a path issue after I installed g++ using macports.

Comment: Yet another reason to switch to libc++ on OSX.

Comment: @user657267 although I find clang++ quite nice and fast, the only compelling reason not to switch to it yet is the lack of support for `openmp`, which I use heavily. I hope it will be supported soon. Best thing is to use other OS for C++ development :)